# Upload disabled due to "Managed Deletable References Detected "

Tags: managed-package, isv, upload, managed-extension

...because the Upload button is disabled and the following error is displayed.

> **Managed Deletable References Detected** 
>   An extension package cannot Refer to any managed deletable components in the base package.

I have no clue what this means and this message is not helping at all.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

“Managed **Deletable** References Detected ” should be "“Managed **Deleted** References Detected ”

As single letter change in the error message would have saved days! And it had nothing to do with Protectable Components in the Base package.

We learned from Salesforce support that we referenced fields of custom objects of the BASE package in a fieldset in the EXTENSION package. We deleted those fields from BASE in a previous release and already upgraded the packaging org of the EXTENSION.

We deleted (and erased) those fields in EXTENSION. Then the error messages was gone and we could upload.

> **UPDATE:** Salesforce just improved the UI in a case we opened and is now showing the problematic components. This makes this kind of error fixable in a second.[image]